# Сортировка списка словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

**Дано**: 2 словаря содержащие список словарей

```
a ={'id': 1,
 'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'result': [{'itemid': '138451',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[foo1]',
             'lastvalue': '0',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for foo1',
             'prevvalue': '0'},
            {'itemid': '97404',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[bar2]',
             'lastvalue': '8',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bar2',
             'prevvalue': '8'},
            {'itemid': '97412',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[baz3]',
             'lastvalue': '2',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bz3',
             'prevvalue': '2'},
            {'itemid': '144281',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[#wtf]',
             'lastvalue': '0',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for #wtf',
             'prevvalue': '0'}]}

b ={'id': 3,
 'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'result': [{'itemid': '138451', 'value_avg': '0'},
            {'itemid': '97404', 'value_avg': '0'},
            {'itemid': '97412', 'value_avg': '0'},
            {'itemid': '144281', 'value_avg': '0'}]}
```

**Задача**: В словарь **b** добавить **key_** и **name** из словаря **а** в случае если совпадают **itemid**.

**Решение**:

```
for idx_b,_ in enumerate(b['result']):
    for idx_a,_ in enumerate(a['result']):
        if b['result'][idx_b]['itemid'] == a['result'][idx_a]['itemid']:
            b['result'][idx_b]['name'] = a['result'][idx_a]['name']
            b['result'][idx_b]['key_'] = a['result'][idx_a]['key_']
```

Собсно вопрос: А как-то можно улучшить путём сокращения кода? Или мб какие встроенные функции для этого существуют?

Comment: @strawdog зачем было удалять метку `python`? Там же ясно написано, что если вопрос касается какой-то конкретной версии, следует использовать _дополнительную_ метку, а не заменять существующую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Улучшить текущий код затруднительно - причина в исходных данных, в их структуре, чтобы оптимизировать/упростить код нужно разобраться с формированием этих структур.

Ради интереса могу привести вариант решения в одну строку? мб что-то подчерпнёте:

```
bd, ad = b['result'], a['result']
_ = [bd[bi].update({i: ad[ai][i]}) for bi, _ in enumerate(bd) for ai, _ in enumerate(ad) for i in ['name', 'key_'] if bd[bi]['itemid'] == ad[ai]['itemid'] and i in ['name', 'key_']]
print b
```

если развернуть, то получится следующее:

```
for bi, _ in enumerate(bd):
    for ai, _ in enumerate(ad):
        for i in ['name', 'key_']:
            if bd[bi]['itemid'] == ad[ai]['itemid'] and i in ['name', 'key_']]:
                bd[bi].update({i: ad[ai][i]})
```

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее, что происходит в этом сильном колдунстве? :)

Comment: Схема [<манипуляции на шаге итерации> <итератор> <условие>]. Смотрите, имеется 3 цикла по `b['result']`, `a['result']` и списку `['name', 'key_']`, выстраивая их в ряд обеспечиваем вложенность, из них получается общий итератор, включающий все комбинации элементов из трёх списков. В конце выражения общее условие, а в начале манипуляции осуществляемые на шаге итерации,  в нём как раз обновляем элементы словаря b значениями из a по ключам из списка `['name', 'key_']`

Comment: Обожаю однострочные циклы! Впрочем использовать это в проде, конечно же, никогда не буду :)

Comment: я бы тоже не использовал python в проде :)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
In [40]: import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

In [41]: cols = ["id", "jsonrpc"]

In [42]: B = pd.io.json.json_normalize(b, ["result"], meta=cols)

In [43]: A = pd.io.json.json_normalize(a, ["result"])

In [44]: res = B.merge(A[["itemid", "name", "key_"]])
```

результат:

```
In [45]: res
Out[45]:
   itemid value_avg id jsonrpc                           name                key_
0  138451         0  3     2.0  Rows changed (delta) for foo1  rows_changed[foo1]
1   97404         0  3     2.0  Rows changed (delta) for bar2  rows_changed[bar2]
2   97412         0  3     2.0   Rows changed (delta) for bz3  rows_changed[baz3]
3  144281         0  3     2.0  Rows changed (delta) for #wtf  rows_changed[#wtf]
```

если хотите получить вложенный словарь (как изначальный `b`):

```
In [46]: d = (res.groupby(cols)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns=cols).to_dict("r"))
                 .reset_index(name="result")
                 .to_dict("r"))

In [47]: d
Out[47]:
[{'id': 3,
  'jsonrpc': '2.0',
  'result': [{'itemid': '138451',
    'value_avg': '0',
    'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for foo1',
    'key_': 'rows_changed[foo1]'},
   {'itemid': '97404',
    'value_avg': '0',
    'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bar2',
    'key_': 'rows_changed[bar2]'},
   {'itemid': '97412',
    'value_avg': '0',
    'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bz3',
    'key_': 'rows_changed[baz3]'},
   {'itemid': '144281',
    'value_avg': '0',
    'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for #wtf',
    'key_': 'rows_changed[#wtf]'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Может легче будет поменять немного структуру данных, например из списков сделать словари с ключами `itemid`, для `dict_a`:

```py
dict_a = {}
for i in a['result']:
    itemid = i.pop['itemid']
    dict_a[itemid] = i
```

А потом итерироваться по `k, v in dict_a.items()` и добавлять `name` и `key_` в `dict_b[k]`

Или же отсортировать списки `result` в `a` и `b` по `itemid` и использовать подход при поиске одинаковых `itemid` как в слиянии отсортированных массивов (пример https://habr.com/ru/post/281675/) - рассматривать списки поэлементно, и если `itemid` равны - то обновлять.

Answer (score 1):

```
for d1, d2 in zip(a['result'], b['result']):
    if d1['itemid'] == d2['itemid']:
        d2.update(key_=d1['key_'], name=d1['name'])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда оставляйте пояснения к коду. Ответы содержащие только код автоматически попадают в очередь проверок.